# CUDA speedup for simple calculations

Tags: c, cuda

I have the following code in `cuda_computation.cu`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <assert.h>

void checkCUDAError(const char *msg);

__global__ void euclid_kernel(float *x, float* y, float* f)
{
  int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int i = blockIdx.x;
  int j = threadIdx.x;
  f[idx] = sqrt((x[i]-x[j])*(x[i]-x[j]) + (y[i]-y[j])*(y[i]-y[j]));
}
int main()
{
  float *xh;
  float *yh;
  float *fh;
  float *xd;
  float *yd;
  float *fd;

  size_t n = 256;
  size_t numBlocks = n;
  size_t numThreadsPerBlock = n;

  size_t memSize = numBlocks * numThreadsPerBlock * sizeof(float);
  xh = (float *) malloc(n * sizeof(float));
  yh = (float *) malloc(n * sizeof(float));
  fh = (float *) malloc(memSize);

  for(int ii(0); ii!=n; ++ii)
    {
      xh[ii] = ii;
      yh[ii] = ii;
    }

  cudaMalloc( (void **) &xd, n * sizeof(float) );
  cudaMalloc( (void **) &yd, n * sizeof(float) );
  cudaMalloc( (void **) &fd, memSize );
  for(int run(0); run!=10000; ++run)
    {
      //change value to avoid optimizations
      xh[0] = ((float)run)/10000.0;
      cudaMemcpy( xd, xh, n * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
      checkCUDAError("cudaMemcpy");
      cudaMemcpy( yd, yh, n * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
      checkCUDAError("cudaMemcpy");
      dim3 dimGrid(numBlocks);
      dim3 dimBlock(numThreadsPerBlock);
      euclid_kernel<<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>( xd, yd, fd );
      cudaThreadSynchronize();
      checkCUDAError("kernel execution");
      cudaMemcpy( fh, fd, memSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
      checkCUDAError("cudaMemcpy");
    }
  cudaFree(xd);
  cudaFree(yd);
  cudaFree(fd);
  free(xh);
  free(yh);
  free(fh);
  return 0;
}

void checkCUDAError(const char *msg)
{
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  if( cudaSuccess != err) 
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: %s: %s.\n", msg, cudaGetErrorString( err) );
      exit(-1);
    }                         
}
```

It takes about 6" to run on an FX QUADRO 380, while the corresponding serial version using just one i7-870 core takes just about 3". Do I miss something? Is the code under optimised in some ways? Or is it just expected behaviour that for simple calculations (like this all-pairs Euclidean distance) the overhead needed to move memory exceeds the computational gain?

Comment: There is no need to save provided indexes such as threadIdx.x in a register.

Comment: @djmj: and the compiler is smart enough to know that. It will make no difference to the register usage of the kernel.

Comment: The Quadro 380 FX is just about the slowest CUDA card ever made, and you are comparing its performance with a very fast x86 processor. It shouldn't be too surprising that there is a performance difference, irrespective of how efficient the GPU code is.

Comment: @talonmies good point! I was assuming that given 56GFLOPS of the Quadro vs. about 10GFLOPS of the i7 (using 8 cores, but i use only one) I could appreciate some speed gain. Are you sure the different speed is on the computational power and not in the overhead? Can someone try the code on more powerful GPUs (I could buy a more powerful GPU, but I need to justify the expense!)?

Comment: @baol: You code takes 3" to execute on GeForce 480GTX, and the most time consuming part is device-to-host memcpy'ing (800ms), while all kernel launches take less then 60ms. A lot of time is also lost due to different overheads. Here is a [snapshot](http://i.zlowiki.ru/120523_26c39ca0.png) of CUDA Visual profiler when running your app on GTX480.

Comment: @baol: It isn't the theoretical FLOP/s that matters in this case, it is the memory bandwidth, because your code should be memory bandwidth limited. Your code only contains 6 FLOP plus the cost of the square root for 4 memory reads and a memory write. That isn't arithmetically intensive enough to allow the GPU to get anywhere near the theoretical peak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are being killed by the time to move the data.
Especially since you are calling the CUDA kernel with individual values, it might be quicker to upload a large set of values as a 1D array and operate on them.

Also sqrt isn't done in HW on Cuda (at least not on my GPU) whereas the CPU has optimized FPU HW for this and is probably 10x faster than the GPU, and for a small job like this is probably keeping all the results in cache between the timign runs.

Comment: I agree on the overhead issue. I tested the same code without the (mostly unneeded) sqrt and the relative results are almost the same.

Comment: All CUDA GPUs have a single precision "approximate" sqrt which is implemented using a reciprocal sqrt hardware instruction and a reciprocal hardware instruction, both of which have the same instruction throughput as a MUL, ADD or MAD (ie. one per clock cycle on the hardware in question). It is this PTX `sqrt.approx.f32` instruction which the compiler should be emitting for this example kernel compiled for the sm_11 architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce your global memory reads since they are expensive.
You have 4 global memory reads per thread which can be reduced to 2 using shared memory.

```
__global__ void euclid_kernel(const float * inX_g, const float* inY_g, float * outF_g)
{
    const unsigned int threadId = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    __shared__ float xBlock_s;
    __shared__ float yBlock_s;

    if(threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        xBlock_s = inX_g[blockIdx.x];
        yBlock_s = inY_g[blockIdx.x];
    }
    __syncthreads();

    float xSub = xBlock_s - inX_g[threadIdx.x];
    float ySub = yBlock_s - inY_g[threadIdx.x];

    outF_g[threadId] = sqrt(xSub * xSub + ySub * ySub);
}
```

You should also test with different block sizes (aslong you have 100% occupancy).

Comment: That kernel code won't even compile.... Shared memory can't be statically initialized. And the original code posted only performs 4 global memory reads, not 8.

Comment: @talonmies +1, was too late yesterday. So only 2 reg can be saved. I should not go to SO right before late bedtime^^

Answer (score 2):

You are splitting the problem so that each block is responsible for a single i vs all 256 j's.  This is bad locality, as those 256 j's have to be reloaded for every block, for a total of 2*256*(256 + 1) loads.  Instead, split your grid so that each block is responsible for a range of, say, 16 i's and 16 j's, which is still 256 blocks*256 threads.  But each block now loads only 2*(16+16) values, for a total or 2*256*32 total loads.  The idea is, reuse each loaded value as many times as possible.  This may not have a huge impact with 256x256, but becomes more and more important as the size scales.

This optimization is used for efficient matrix multiplies, which have a similar locality problem.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling, or google for "optimized matrix multiply" for more details.  And perhaps the matrix multiplication kernel in the NVIDIA SDK gives some details and ideas.